# Missing dependency for hdf5: totem

Tags: hdf5, totem

while installing the following command I get the error as shown below

```
parag@parag:~/torch-hdf5$ sudo luarocks make hdf5-0-0.rockspec LIBHDF5_LIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"

Missing dependencies for hdf5:
totem 

Error: Could not satisfy dependency: totem
```

Totem is already installed.

```
parag@parag:~$ sudo apt-get install totem
[sudo] password for parag: 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
totem is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 102 not upgraded.
parag@parag:~$
```

What I should do now?

Answer (score 6):

Future someone, the following two lines helped me solve the issue:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deepmind/torch-totem/master/rocks/totem-0-0.rockspec
sudo luarocks install totem-0-0.rockspec
```

You may have to restart your system to get it working!