# Missing dependency for hdf5: totem Error: Failed cloning git repository

Tags: hdf5, torch, totem

```
dlualkuma57985:torch-hdf5 asuma2$ luarocks make hdf5-0-0.rockspec
```

as per given in this link [Missing dependency for hdf5: totem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360555/missing-dependency-for-hdf5-totem) i tried

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deepmind/torch-totem/master/rocks/totem-0-0.rockspec
sudo luarocks install totem-0-0.rockspec
```

but for

```
sudo luarocks install totem-0-0.rockspec
```

it is giving me following error:

```
Using totem-0-0.rockspec... switching to 'build' mode
Cloning into 'torch-totem'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.253.113]: errno=Connection refused
github.com[1: 192.30.253.112]: errno=Connection refused


Error: Failed cloning git repository.
```

Comment: does `luarocks install totem` work?

Comment: No. It's giving the same error as mentioned above. Infact when i am trying to install loadcaffe by "luarocks install loadcaffe" , still i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

It has been resolved. There was some issue with network, so instead i connected to hotspot of mobile and then run the command.